# How do I correctly link a shared object (.so file) in a makefile when cross-compiling?

Tags: linux, c++11, makefile, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I have some C++ code on an openSuse platform that I need to compile to be executed on a different linux-based target. Part of the code is a dynamic library `libfoo.so`. I compile everything with `make` and then copy the compiled executable `prog` together with the `libfoo.so` to the target. When I then run the executable, I get some errors indicating the libfoo could not be initialized. I've tried everything I could find to tell the executable where it can find the `libfoo.so` but I still get the error.

**Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? I feel like it could be an error in the Makefile.**

I am very new to C++ and using Makefiles in general, and on top of it all, the target runs kind of a proprietary linux version, so I cannot provide much information about it. I do have the appropriate compiler for it though.

My directory structure on the openSuse platform:

```
|src
|--Foolib
|----foolib.h
|----libfoo.so
|--Otherlib
|----otherlib.h
|----otherlib.hpp
|---+OtherlibSrcDirectory
|--bar.cpp
|--bar.h
|--Makefile
```

Directory structure on the target:

```
|program
|--libfoo.so
|--prog
```

My Makefile:

```
LIBS = -LFoolib -lfoo
INC = -I OtherLib -I Foolib
CXXFLAGS += -lpthread -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP $(INC)
LDFLAGS = '-Wl,-rpath,$$ORIGIN'
SRC_FILES = bar.cpp
OBJ =  $(SRC_FILES:%.cpp=%.o)

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS) -c $<
```

Basically, `bar.h` includes `Foolib/foolib.h` as well as `Otherlib/OtherlibSrcDirectory` and `bar.cpp` includes `bar.h`. Then some functions from `foolib.h` are called in `bar.cpp` and they return error values. If necessary I can provide some more insights into the code but I'll leave it out for now to keep it a bit shorter.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - a sequence of shell commands which reproduce your issue. Don't forget to provide "some errors indicating the libfoo could not be initialized" and expand on "I've tried everything I could find to tell the executable where it can find the libfoo.so".

Comment: Thanks for the advice @yugr . Regarding the errors: all libfoo-functions return an error value. If it is 0, there are no errors. I always get an error value that is explained in the documentation as "Libfoo could not be initialized.". And by "I've tried everything I could find..." I meant that I tried to adjust rpath and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tell the executable where it can find the .so. I also tried to put the .so into the executable's directory as well as /lib. I am not sure if I can provide MVCE due to the target's proprietary OS but I will give it a try...

Comment: "Libfoo could not be initialized" - AFAIK this is not a standard error message emitted by Glibc so most likely some libfoo-specific startup logic fails.

Comment: @yugr I think you're right. I tried to use a libfoo shell command on the target system, which is something that should work without problems because it's completely unrelated to my code, but I got an error message "Unable to setup Libfoo". I'll have to look into the target system's configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake.

libfoo.so was already on the target machine and it was located in the correct folder (/lib). My program had been able to find it without problems.

My mistake: I executed my program on the target machine without root permissions.
Without root permissions, I am not allowed to initialize Foolib.

`sudo ./prog` fixed everything.